# Is there a way to load libraries so that they will only be available inside the local scope?

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is to dynamically load a modified version of jQuery and other libraries so that these modified versions can only be accessed inside the local scope from where I'm calling them and avoid conflicts with other versions of the same libraries. For example:

```
//Some global code that uses regular jQuery
(function(win, doc, undefined){
   loadMyJQuery();
   //Some code that uses my modified version
})(window,document);
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You could `evel()` the XHR rexuest to your javascript file. But it is a horrible solution and you should first consider changing the program concept. Ask yourself if you really need to load whole jQuery.

Comment: You're totally right. The best thing would be to re-think the whole code, but I'm obligged to use that jQuery and other modified libraries(that I haven't coded).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign each library to it's own variable by using jQuery.noConflict()
and pass that

```
(function($){

})(yourjQuery)
```